# Macro that colors top row and last column

Tags: excel, vba, colors

I am new to macro vba I want the macro to add colour yellow to top row i.e. header row and the last column which is blank. The macro should colour the last column which blanks only till where the corresponding rows have data, not the entire column.

below is my code... I get error "error code 1004 application-defined or object-defined"

```
Private Sub CommandButton8_Click()
    
    'Hide column A to E and color.
    
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("POL").Range("A1", Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToRight)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
    
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("POL").Columns("A:E").Hidden = True
    
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:04"))
    
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("POD").Columns("A:E").Hidden = True
    
    
End Sub
```

Excel screen for reference.

[image: Top row Header and last column]

The macro should colour top row header and the last column... The last column is blank so it should colour till only where the corresponding row/columns have data.
[image: Like this should be the output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use your used range to get the last row and last column at same time so long as you don't have extra data in the sheet that isn't included in this "table".

```
Dim lastcell As Range, rng As Range

With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("POL")
    Set lastcell = .Cells(UsedRange.Rows.Count, UsedRange.Columns.Count)
    Set rng = .Range(.Cells(1, lastcell.Column), .Cells(lastcell.Row, lastcell.Column))
End With

rng.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
```

Update:
Try this one then which finds the last row using the specific column. I set it to use the column before the last one but you can set it to whichever column has the lastrow in it.

```
Private Sub CommandButton8_Click()
    
    'Hide column A to E and color.
    
    Dim lastcolumn As Long, lastrow As Long
    
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("POL")
        lastcolumn = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        lastrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, lastcolumn - 1).End(xlUp).Row
        'lastrow = .range("A" & rows.Count).end(xlup).row  'Use this one if you want to set a specific column to find the last row.
        
        .Range("A1", .Cells(1, lastcolumn)).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        .Range(.Cells(1, lastcolumn), .Cells(lastrow, lastcolumn)).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
    End With
    
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("POL").Columns("A:E").Hidden = True
    
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:04"))
    
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("POD").Columns("A:E").Hidden = True
    
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @Simon, the code has highlighted only cell A1 i.e. column A header. And not the entire row and last column

Comment: SOme1 please answer

Comment: Please see my revised answer.